# PHP or Use of Exe file?

Tags: php, exe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [websites urls without file extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322747/websites-urls-without-file-extension)

I'm not sure what it is exactly but after looking at sites like Facebook and others I often see urls like http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=examplequery

My question on this is sites like Facebook and others are written in PHP but don't always use the .php extension on the end like youtube's search for example instead of results.asp or results.php it just uses /results? and then adds the query string on the end.

Can anyone tell me are these using PHP/ASP.Net or is it an EXE file like a cgi program? I'm confused.

Thanks in advance for anyone who can clear this up for me.

Comment: URLs don't necessarily map directly to files. Even in PHP, you can use rewrites and such. But no, it's not an EXE file (YouTube doesn't run on Windows servers anyways) and no, it's not PHP. YouTube is written in Python, if I recall correctly...

Answer (score 0):

It's not an exe file. I think in PHP you can do that by using .htaccess to remove / hide PHP extension but I don't have any idea how to do that in ASP or other language

Comment: Thanks guys! That pretty much answers my question :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use MVC model to develop your site in PHP, here is an article(http://tonymarston.net/php-mysql/model-view-controller.html) to introduce basic theory, you can take a look. BTW, if you are developing a new site, you can consider using [Drupal](http://drupal.org),it should be very easy to implement MVC model with no extension.